# swiftでiPhoneのオーディオ出力を下部スピーカーで鳴らす方法は

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift4

swiftでiPhoneのオーディオ出力を下部スピーカーで鳴らすのにAudioUnitクラスを使うようだが具体的なやり方がわかりません。AVAudioPlayerで電話のスピーカーからのオーディオ出力は出来ています。
ご存知の方、お知恵を拝借させてください。

Comment: ご質問の内容は以前の[こちらのご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/47907/13972)と実質的に全く同じ内容なのではないでしょうか?このような場合、新しい質問を再度投稿するのではなく、元のご質問を「編集」するようにして下さい。編集することによりアクティブリストの上位に来ますので、古い質問でも埋もれたままになることはありません。

Comment: 同じ質問です。しかし、自分なりに調べてAudioUnitクラスを使えば目的を果たせると思いましたが、その先が分からないので　再度　質問しました。

Comment: @jYama 同じ質問の場合は前の質問を編集するか、コメントや回答がついていない場合は削除して作り直してください

Comment: 以前の質問を削除しました。申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: @jYama さん、今後同じような状況では古い質問を削除して新しい質問を書き直すのでなく、元の質問を編集するようにしてください。自分なりに調べた結果を元の質問に追記されれば良いことかと思います。

Comment: AVAudioSessionのoverrideOutputAudioPortでspeakerを指定したら外部スピーカーから再生できました。
自己解決しました。
 
     let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
     do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            //エラー処理
        }
  do {
            try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
        } catch let error as NSError {
           //エラー処理
        }
 do {
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            //エラー処理
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVAudioSessionのoverrideOutputAudioPortでspeakerを指定したら外部スピーカーから再生できました。
自己解決しました。

```
   let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
   do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        //エラー処理
    }
do {
        try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
    } catch let error as NSError {
       //エラー処理
    }
do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        //エラー処理
    }
```

Comment: 解決方法の投稿ありがとうございます。すでに質問から時間が経っているので、すぐに「承認」が可能かと思います。承認の方も忘れずにお願いします。